# ¿como puedo quitar el slug # de mi pagina de Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

no encuentro la manera de poder quitar los slug #servicios y #contacto de mi pagina web.

www.teksolutions.mx

Tengo instalado un tema en mi sitio web.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estás utilizando esos slug a modo de anchor, para que la página se desplace automáticamente al bloque con la ID indicada despues del #

En el caso de querer quitar los enlaces anchor perderás esta funcionalidad por lo que la página dejará de desplazarse a no ser que programes un código para realizarlo de forma silenciosa.

Si se quiere quitar se debería modificar el enlace con #, en el caso de servicios veo que tienes el slider principal con un botón que lleva a #servicios, sería modificar ese enlace para eliminarlo.

Espero que te haya ayudado